# Webview back clears forms and possibly reloads page

Tags: android, webview

I am noticing strange/different behavior in Android webview compared to for example stock internet browser. Problem is the following :
When filling out a form on a first page and then going to next page (for example in our app we have a register form in a webview with link to terms and conditions under it) when back is pressed registration form is shown again but fields are cleared. This does not happen in internet browser on the device and I was wondering is this a bug, expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong using

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    webview.goBack();
    }
//Code is literally this simple and settings on webview are 
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
wv.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Should I use some different approach to go back in history or is there some setting that I missed that enables required behavior

Comment: It's not great to rely on that feature even for PC browsers.  I've times when firefox has lost the form content for no obvious reason.  To get round this, you can either use ajax to quietly save the content of the form (think save draft not submit) or you can do this on all links / buttons out of the page that are likely to result in the user coming back to the page.

Comment: Thank you for your response. About the ajax part this could be done but the problem there would be since user viewing registration form does not have session (at least session that we track) on our servers so we don't have a "place" where to put his data. Saving this data as cookies on users browser could probably do similar thing but I was thinking that there might be some reliable way to tell webview to do this automatically.